# Brute force ssh login attempt on AWS t2.micro

Tags: ssh, brute-force

I have some confusion in understanding the security groups itself i guess.

The login attempts are being made to different ports , here are the logs

```
Jan 08 00:00:13 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6067]: Disconnecting invalid user test2 75.121.129.252 port 49340: Too many authent
Jan 08 00:00:19 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6070]: Invalid user test2 from 75.121.129.252 port 49560
Jan 08 00:00:19 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6070]: Received disconnect from 75.121.129.252 port 49560:11: disconnected by user 
Jan 08 00:00:19 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6070]: Disconnected from invalid user test2 75.121.129.252 port 49560 [preauth]
Jan 08 00:00:26 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6072]: Invalid user contador from 75.121.129.252 port 49764
Jan 08 00:00:26 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6072]: Received disconnect from 75.121.129.252 port 49764:11: disconnected by user 
Jan 08 00:00:26 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6072]: Disconnected from invalid user contador 75.121.129.252 port 49764 [preauth]
Jan 08 00:00:34 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6076]: Invalid user duni from 75.121.129.252 port 49974
Jan 08 00:00:34 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6076]: Received disconnect from 75.121.129.252 port 49974:11: disconnected by user 
Jan 08 00:00:34 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6076]: Disconnected from invalid user duni 75.121.129.252 port 49974 [preauth]
Jan 08 00:00:40 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6078]: Invalid user pi from 75.121.129.252 port 50186
Jan 08 00:00:41 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6078]: Received disconnect from 75.121.129.252 port 50186:11: disconnected by user 
Jan 08 00:00:41 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6078]: Disconnected from invalid user pi 75.121.129.252 port 50186 [preauth]
Jan 08 00:00:47 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6080]: Invalid user baikal from 75.121.129.252 port 50388
Jan 08 00:00:47 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6080]: Received disconnect from 75.121.129.252 port 50388:11: disconnected by user 
Jan 08 00:00:47 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6080]: Disconnected from invalid user baikal 75.121.129.252 port 50388 [preauth]
Jan 08 00:03:04 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6090]: Received disconnect from 167.114.96.156 port 55584:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan 08 00:03:04 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6090]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 167.114.96.156 port 55584 [preaut
Jan 08 00:04:03 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6095]: Received disconnect from 221.181.185.72 port 12784:11:  [preauth]
Jan 08 00:04:03 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6095]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 221.181.185.72 port 12784 [preaut
Jan 08 00:05:01 ip-172-31-10-252 CRON[6109]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 08 00:05:01 ip-172-31-10-252 CRON[6110]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jan 08 00:05:01 ip-172-31-10-252 CRON[6109]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan 08 00:05:31 ip-172-31-10-252 sshd[6121]: Received disconnect from 143.110.182.219 port 34468:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
```

as you can see the attacker is using ephemeral ports to brute force ssh login ?
my questions are

1. why is the instance receiving this connections?( i am running my instances behind a security group that has only 22, 80 ,443 open to world) shouldn't the packets be dropped before reaching the instance itself?.
2. the cpu usage at the same time went high for which my instance started showing health check failure and became available. is it expected when someone try to bruteforce  ssh login ?
3. is the security group not sufficient enough to run my poc workloads? does brute-force ssh login really kill the server with high cpu?

if the question sounded silly to you , please share me the materials i should go through to understand it myself. Thanks